# How to set result variable in SELECT query to ALL (*) in Sparql Query using Jena

Tags: sparql, jena

I am making a SPARQL Query apache Jena. i have the following code:

```
        Query Q = QueryFactory.make();
        Q.setQueryPattern(QueryBody);
        Q.setQuerySelectType();
        Q.setResultVars(" * ");
```

The first 3 lines are working but the last one whch is: Q.setResultVars(" * "); is not working. How can i make the SELECT variable to *. so that i will retrieve all values?
Thank you!

Comment: Javadoc is **always** your friend: [`Q.setQueryResultStar(true);`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/Query.html#setQueryResultStar-boolean-)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @AKSW ...

> Javadoc is **always** your friend: [Q.setQueryResultStar(true);](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/Query.html#setQueryResultStar-boolean-)